# Node js - pass parameters to build

Tags: node.js, webpack

Trying to pass parameters to server side part of app.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "better-npm-run build",
  },
"betterScripts": {
    "build": {
      "command": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.production.js",
      "env": {
        "TEST": "MYTEST",
      }
    },
```

webpack.config.production.js:

```
const client={...}
const server = {
  entry: {
    server: ['babel-polyfill', './src/server/index.js']
  },
  target: 'node',
  output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: moduleObj,
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
}

module.exports = [client, server];
```

then in code:

```
console.log(process.env.TEST); 
// undefined
```

When server runs in development mode without webpack build paramaters passed though:

```
"dev-server": {
      "command": "nodemon --inspect src/server/index.js --exec babel-node",
      "env": {
        "TEST": "NO_PROBLEM_THERE",
      }
    }
```

It has to be some webpack config issue, but I don't know what it's exactly...
Any ideas?